# Visualforce page works but fails when embedded [Too many query rows: 50001]

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am running into a strange problem wherby I have a (quite complicated) VisualForce page that I pass a couple of parameters to when running. This page runs fine.

```
Example URL: https://force.com/apex/medicalforecast?t=SUMMARY&y=2013
```

However, if I embed it into another simple visualforce page with the following code I get a "System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001" error.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:include pageName="MedicalForecast" />
</apex:page>

Example URL: https://force.com/apex/Forecast?t=SUMMARY&y=2013
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Is there additional queries run when embedding one VisualForce page into another?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm

especially that part:

> 1. The constructor methods on the associated custom controller or controller extension classes are called, instantiating the controller
>      objects.
> 2. If the page contains any custom components, they are created and the constructor methods on any associated custom controllers or
>      controller extensions are executed.

So in the first initial request the constructors (and getters) of main page and all embedded pages/components will fire to render the initial state. That means it's all one transaction, one context and the 50K rows limit is shared across them.

Maybe you can annotate your pages with `readonly="true"` or try to make the constructors slim (not wasting too many queries). Put a "fetch data" button & action method - user will have to make 1 more click but this will count as separate action = fresh 50K rows limit.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the response but I must admit to still being a little confused. The page that does the embedding as seen above has no constructor and has no queries that it runs on it's own. Are you saying that the embedded page "medicalforecast" is actually constructed twice upon the page loading and therefore hits the 50k limit?

Comment: Just to add, adding readonly="true" to embedding page does allow this to work! I still struggle to understand the logic around the embedded constructor being hit twice.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Apply a debug log to your user and check what queries are run, how many lines do they return in total... But it'd be weird if the parent page doesn't have any queries on it's own. Is this the only `<apex:include>` on that page? And no more embeds like `<c:componentName>`, templates etc are used?

Comment: I did attempt to use the debug log, however run into the same old problem of the code being too complicated and quickly hitting the debug output limit. The parent page is literally as pasted in my original question - 3 lines with no constructor - hence my confusion! Appreciate the help.

Comment: No idea why they'd behave differently then... Go to debug log filters, tune everything that's not related to Database / SOQL / Profiling down, retry? It's of course with same user or something so the logic executes same way?

Comment: I've tried that - still outputs so much unneeded information that the debug log fills up. It's with the same user. I think I'm just going to leave it as the "Read-Only" option appears to work! Cheers